# How do I transform df using pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, transpose

I have the following dataframe snippet:

```
predictor   b   z   pvalue  model   ss
age_raw 1.026695    4.678675    2.89E-06    composite_outcome_nonenglish    1
elixsum 1.228125    8.514571    1.67E-17    composite_outcome_nonenglish    1
age_raw 1.087716    0.228507    0.819252    composite_outcome_english   0
elixsum 1.760882    1.68492     0.092004    composite_outcome_english   0
```

that I need to transpose into a multi-index column dataframe using `model` as the highest level and (`b`, `z`, `pvalue`, `ss`) as the secondary level the `predictor` as rows:

```
                    model                              model
          composite_outcome_nonenglish            composite_outcome_english 
           b        z           pvalue   ss           b         z           pvalue  ss
age_raw 1.026695    4.678675    2.89E-06 0            1.087716  0.228507    0.819252 1
elixsum 1.228125    8.514571    1.67E-17 0            1.760882  1.68492     0.092004 1
```

I've tried all sorts of groupings, and stacking and unstacking, etc., and for the life of me, I cannot get this right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set index with `unstack` + `stack`

```
out = df.set_index(['predictor','model']).stack().unstack(level=[1,2])
Out[366]: 
model     composite_outcome_nonenglish            ... composite_outcome_english     
                                     b         z  ...                    pvalue   ss
predictor                                         ...                               
age_raw                       1.026695  4.678675  ...                  0.819252  0.0
elixsum                       1.228125  8.514571  ...                  0.092004  0.0
```

Comment: This is the route I was taking, but got stuck on. It's the only reason I'm accepting this as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You want `pivot` and `swaplevel`:

```
(df.pivot(index='predictor', columns='model')
   .swaplevel(0,1, axis=1)
   .sort_index(axis=1)
)
```

Output:

```
model       composite_outcome_english               composite_outcome_nonenglish
            b           pvalue      ss  z           b           pvalue      ss          z
predictor                               
age_raw     1.087716    0.819252    0   0.228507    1.026695    2.890000e-06    1   4.678675
elixsum     1.760882    0.092004    0   1.684920    1.228125    1.670000e-17    1   8.514571
```